# Why are harmonic oscillations problems solved the way they are?

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations

In differential equations, there are the various methods to solve first and second order diff-eq’s.

For 2nd order equations like those seen with harmonic oscillations problems or simple harmonic motion, we have things like damping frequency, neper frequency, and frequency. Then we look at whether omega is greater than, less than, or equal to neper, and write the solution based on that.

Why is there a need for that when we have other methods to solve 2nd order equations? Does it have to do with physics? In my electrical engineering classes we are now solving these problems but with circuits.

Comment: Welcome to Math Stack Exchange. Please provide the context (reference) from where you got such kind of question in your mind.